# How to tell if heroku is pushing the correct files

Tags: heroku, push, commit

I think I am pushing my master branch to heroku, but when I visit the page none of the file structure is there. For example if I visit http://heroku-site/pages/home I get a "We're sorry but something wen't wrong error" The app works fine locally. How do I know the files are up there. Here are my steps. Not sure why it's not working.

1) git status

2) git add .

3) git commit -m "Some Message"

4) git push heroku master

**Heroku logs**

```
 2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 heroku[router]: GET quiet-flower-7747.heroku.com/pages/home dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pages/home] miss
2012-02-03T02:44:22+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 24.87.81.230 - - [03/Feb/2012:02:44:22 +0000] "GET /pages/home HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7" quiet-flower-7747.heroku.com
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pages/home" for 24.87.81.230 at 2012-02-02 18:46:45 -0800
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2584572968946772396__call__962583124295019556__callbacks'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:241:in `fetch'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 heroku[router]: GET quiet-flower-7747.heroku.com/pages/home dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T02:46:45+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pages/home] miss
2012-02-03T02:46:46+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 24.87.81.230 - - [03/Feb/2012:02:46:46 +0000] "GET /pages/home HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7" quiet-flower-7747.heroku.com
```

Comment: What is the output of `$ heroku logs`? It should give an idea of why it's throwing an error.

Comment: I added the heroku output, sorry you said the logs. Fixing that

Comment: Are you using a database? If so have you configured pgsql (pg gem) and run heroku rake db:migrate?

Comment: there is no database as of yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer lies here:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):`

I notice you're using EventMachine, which then leads me to ask how you're connecting to the database.  Ensure that you're using ENV["DATABASE_URL"] as your DB connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if your repository files are up there by cloning from your Heroku git repo to some other directory on your machine and making sure they're all there.

When you say "when I visit the page none of the file structure is there", what do you mean exactly?

If `/pages/home` is supposed to display the file listing from your file system, then this might not work in Heroku. I know that your Dyno sees a read-only file system and they might be  doing some other funny stuff there as well.